# tikz, automata, forcing size of self-loops to be identical

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, automata

On the following picture that uses
the tikz automata library, I would like
all self-loops to have the same size
(i.e. namely the size of the self-loop
attached to the rightmost-lower node
labelled by 1).

But currently the size of a self-loop
depends on the size of the node as well
as on the orientation of the self-loop.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} \usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}
\usepackage{pifont}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{every state/.style={draw,rectangle,rounded corners=2pt,inner sep=2pt,minimum width=12pt,minimum height=12pt}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,semithick]
\node[state,accepting] (1) at (1.5,1.5) {\ding{189}\ding{172}};
\node[state,accepting] (2) at (1.5,3.0) {\ding{188}\ding{173}\ding{172}};
\node[state,accepting] (3) at (1.5,4.5) {\ding{177}\ding{176}\ding{173}\ding{172}};
\node[state,accepting] (4) at (3.0,4.5) {\ding{176}\ding{173}\ding{172}};
\node[state,accepting] (5) at (3.0,3.0) {\ding{175}\ding{174}\ding{172}};
\node[state,accepting] (6) at (4.5,3.0) {\ding{174}\ding{172}};
\node[state,accepting] (7) at (3.0,1.5) {\ding{173}\ding{172}};
\node[state,accepting] (8) at (4.5,1.5) {\ding{172}};
\draw[<-] (8.south east) -- node[sloped] {} ++(2.3mm,-2.3mm);
\node[state,accepting,color=gray] (14) at (1.5,0.0) {\ding{174}\ding{172}};
\node[state,accepting,color=gray] (15) at (3.0,6.0) {\ding{188}\ding{173}\ding{172}};
\node[state,accepting,color=gray] (16) at (4.5,0.0) {\ding{188}\ding{173}\ding{172}};
\node[state,accepting,color=gray] (17) at (4.5,4.5) {\ding{172}};
\path
(1) edge [in=-150,out=-120,loop] node[below] {.} (1)
(1) edge[bend angle=70,bend right] node[below=0,sloped] {.} (8)
(1) edge node[below=0,sloped] {.} (7)
(1) edge[densely dotted] node[below=0,sloped] {.} (14)
(2) edge [loop left] node {.} (2)
(2) edge node[below=0,sloped] {.} (5)
(3) edge [in=120,out=150,loop] node[above] {.} (3)
(3) edge[bend angle=70,bend right] node[below=0,sloped] {.} (1)
(3) edge node[below=0,sloped] {.} (2)
(3) edge[bend angle=16,bend right] node[below=0,sloped] {.} (5)
(4) edge[densely dotted] node[below=0,sloped] {.} (17)
(4) edge[densely dotted] node[below=0,sloped] {.} (15)
(4) edge node[below=0,sloped] {.} (5)
(5) edge node[below=0,sloped] {.} (8)
(5) edge node[below=0,sloped] {.} (3)
(5) edge node[below=0,sloped] {.} (6)
(6) edge[bend angle=18,bend right] node[below=0,sloped] {.} (8)
(6) edge node[below=0,sloped] {.} (4)
(6) edge [loop right] node {.} (6)
(7) edge node[below=0,sloped] {.} (8)
(7) edge [loop below] node {.} (7)
(7) edge node[above=0,sloped] {.} (5)
(8) edge [loop right] node {.} (8)
(8) edge[bend angle=18,bend left] node[below=0,sloped] {.} (7)
(8) edge node[below=0,sloped] {.} (6)
(16) edge[densely dotted] node[below=0,sloped] {.} (8);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can adjust the looseness, but when you say that all the loops should have the same size: how do you define size here? This is important for the diagonal loops, in which the distance from the start to the turning point does not coincide with the distance from the turning point to the end.

Comment: Somehow, for the diagonal, I don't have any formal definition for the size (it could be the distance between the inflexion point of the loop and the border of the state, but as said it is not too important). What do you mean by "adjust looseness"?

Comment: The size of the loop is controlled by the looseness key. The original definition of the loop is in the `topaths` library and reads `tikzset{loop/.style=                    {to path={
  \pgfextra{\let\tikztotarget=\tikztostart}
  [looseness=8,min distance=5mm,every loop]
  \tikz@to@curve@path
  }}}`, so it has originally looseness 8.

Comment: Does it means that I have to find the relation between this looseness parameter and the width of a state ?

Comment: This might be one way but a very cumbersome one. The looseness controls the location of the control points, so there is no easy correspondence between the looseness and the distance of the turning point. It might make more sense to construct the path in a different way, i.e. a different `to path`. However, to make this happen one needs a precise prescription for the outcome. For instance, do you want the distance between start and end points to depend on the node size.

Comment: I see two options: (1) the distance between the start and end points is fixed or (2) the distance between (i) the point located at the middle of the start and end points and (ii) the inflexion point of the loop is constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this goes in the right direction. The loop is done via a pic since it is somewhat hard to hack the edge path enough. (I also changed the positioning of the nodes from manual to matrix. One could simplify this further but I wanted to keep the node names.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows,automata,calc}
\usepackage{pifont}
\tikzset{pics/sloped loop/.style={code={
    \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/sloped loop parameters/##1}}
    \tikzset{/tikz/sloped loop parameters/.cd,#1}
    \draw[/tikz/sloped loop parameters/style,pic actions]
    (\pv{node}.\pv{angle}+\pv{opening angle}) 
    to[out=\pv{angle}+\pv{opening angle},in=\pv{angle}+90]
     ($(\pv{node}.\pv{angle})+(\pv{angle}:\pv{distance})$) coordinate(aux)
    to[out=\pv{angle}-90,in=\pv{angle}-\pv{opening angle}]
     (\pv{node}.\pv{angle}-\pv{opening angle});}},
sloped loop parameters/.cd,node/.initial=A,
opening angle/.initial=15,style/.initial={->},
set/.code={\typeout{set #1}\tikzset{slope loop parameters/.cd,#1}},
angle/.initial=90,distance/.initial=0.5cm}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{every state/.style={draw,rectangle,rounded corners=2pt,inner sep=2pt,minimum width=12pt,minimum height=12pt}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\matrix[nodes={state,accepting},column sep=1cm,row sep=1cm]
{
& \node[color=gray] (15)  {\ding{188}\ding{173}\ding{172}}; & \\
\node (3) {\ding{177}\ding{176}\ding{173}\ding{172}}; &
\node (4) {\ding{176}\ding{173}\ding{172}}; &
\node[color=gray] (17) {\ding{172}}; \\
\node (2) {\ding{188}\ding{173}\ding{172}}; &
\node (5) {\ding{175}\ding{174}\ding{172}}; &
\node (6) {\ding{174}\ding{172}}; \\
\node (1) {\ding{189}\ding{172}}; &
\node (7) {\ding{173}\ding{172}}; &
\node (8) {\ding{172}}; \\
\node[color=gray] (14)  {\ding{174}\ding{172}}; & &
\node[color=gray] (16)  {\ding{188}\ding{173}\ding{172}};\\
};
\begin{scope}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,semithick]
%\node[state,accepting] (1) at (1.5,1.5) {\ding{189}\ding{172}};
%\node[state,accepting] (2) at (1.5,3.0) {\ding{188}\ding{173}\ding{172}};
%\node[state,accepting] (3) at (1.5,4.5) {\ding{177}\ding{176}\ding{173}\ding{172}};
%\node[state,accepting] (4) at (3.0,4.5) {\ding{176}\ding{173}\ding{172}};
%\node[state,accepting] (5) at (3.0,3.0) {\ding{175}\ding{174}\ding{172}};
%\node[state,accepting] (6) at (4.5,3.0) {\ding{174}\ding{172}};
%\node[state,accepting] (7) at (3.0,1.5) {\ding{173}\ding{172}};
%\node[state,accepting] (8) at (4.5,1.5) {\ding{172}};
\draw[<-] (8.south east) -- node[sloped] {} ++(2.3mm,-2.3mm);
%\node[state,accepting,color=gray] (14) at (1.5,0.0) {\ding{174}\ding{172}};
%\node[state,accepting,color=gray] (15) at (3.0,6.0) {\ding{188}\ding{173}\ding{172}};
%\node[state,accepting,color=gray] (16) at (4.5,0.0) {\ding{188}\ding{173}\ding{172}};
%\node[state,accepting,color=gray] (17) at (4.5,4.5) {\ding{172}};
\path
pic{sloped loop={node=1,angle=-135}} (aux) node[below] {.}
%(1) edge [in=-150,out=-120,loop] node[below] {.} (1)
(1) edge[bend angle=70,bend right] node[below=0,sloped] {.} (8)
(1) edge node[below=0,sloped] {.} (7)
(1) edge[densely dotted] node[below=0,sloped] {.} (14)
pic{sloped loop={node=2,angle=180}} (aux) node[left] {.}
%(2) edge [loop left] node {.} (2)
(2) edge node[below=0,sloped] {.} (5)
pic{sloped loop={node=3,angle=135}} (aux) node[above] {.}
%(3) edge [in=120,out=150,loop] node[above] {.} (3)
(3) edge[bend angle=70,bend right] node[below=0,sloped] {.} (1)
(3) edge node[below=0,sloped] {.} (2)
(3) edge[bend angle=16,bend right] node[below=0,sloped] {.} (5)
(4) edge[densely dotted] node[below=0,sloped] {.} (17)
(4) edge[densely dotted] node[below=0,sloped] {.} (15)
(4) edge node[below=0,sloped] {.} (5)
(5) edge node[below=0,sloped] {.} (8)
(5) edge node[below=0,sloped] {.} (3)
(5) edge node[below=0,sloped] {.} (6)
(6) edge[bend angle=18,bend right] node[below=0,sloped] {.} (8)
(6) edge node[below=0,sloped] {.} (4)
pic{sloped loop={node=6,angle=0}} (aux) node[right] {.}
%(6) edge [loop right] node {.} (6)
(7) edge node[below=0,sloped] {.} (8)
pic{sloped loop={node=7,angle=-90}} (aux) node[below] {.}
%(7) edge [loop below] node {.} (7)
(7) edge node[above=0,sloped] {.} (5)
pic{sloped loop={node=8,angle=0}} (aux) node[right] {.}
%(8) edge [loop right] node {.} (8)
(8) edge[bend angle=18,bend left] node[below=0,sloped] {.} (7)
(8) edge node[below=0,sloped] {.} (6)
(16) edge[densely dotted] node[below=0,sloped] {.} (8);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]